# How to specify config file with sbt start in Play application?

Tags: playframework, sbt, config

I have what I assume to be a common use case for developing and deploying a Play 2.3.6 application:

- In development, I run `sbt run` and the application uses `application.conf` as expected.
- In production I would like to use `sbt start` and specify the config file, `production.conf`, which resides in the same directory as the dev config file (which is `<project root>/conf/`)

Following the instructions under the "Specifying alternative configuration file" heading on the [official docs page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration), like so:

```
$ sbt start -Dconfig.file=/full/path/to/project/conf/production.conf
```

The application starts without error, but I can inspect the web application and see that it is loading my `application.conf` development values, not my production values found in `production.conf`.

I also tried the suggested approach:

```
$ sbt start -Dconfig.resource=production.conf
```

And the server fails to start with error:

```
[error] com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: production.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: production.conf
```

Has anyone else figured out how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After a few wasted hours, I figured it out. Using quotes as follows passes the parameter correctly:

```
$ sbt "start -Dconfig.resource=production.conf"
```

Also, if you need to specify the port number, make sure it comes *after* the config option, **otherwise it will be ignored:**

```
$ sbt "start -Dconfig.resource=production.conf 9001"
```

Comment: Also... I just realized that if you specify the port number, it must come _after_ the config option, otherwise the option will be ignored.

Comment: I'm trying use play with default configuration file ( application.conf ) but I still have the same problems. There is application.conf file within conf directory. But when I execute the `sbt start` command the same error is thrown

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000310/play-framework-overriding-application-conf-values-based-on-environment/48012753#48012753