# Play framework overriding `application.conf` values based on environment

Tags: scala, playframework

Play 2.6.x Scala

I have a default `application.conf` within the folder `{project}/conf/` but I'd like to override some values depending on the environment by passing in the respective file as command-line arguments ([as detailed in the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration)):

`sbt run -Dconfig.file=/conf/qa.conf` or `sbt run -Dconfig.resource=qa.conf`

But I'm not able to get play to pick up the overrides. Here's my file directory:

```
application  
    |- playApp1
    |- playApp2  
       |-- conf  
           |-- application.conf 
           |-- qa.conf
```

My `build.sbt` makes playApp2 the default project on load. And I have confirmed that the defulat `application.conf` is working -- just the override is not.

Thanks for any ideas!

--

**Update**

Here are the HOCON files play uses. `application.conf`

```
platform {
  scheme = "http"
  host = "localhost:8080"
}
```

and the overrides as provided in `qa.conf`

```
include "application.conf"

platform {
  scheme = "https"
  host = "ea311.34.com"
}
```

Comment: Please show your `application.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you provide the command line argument first

```
sbt -Dconfig.resource=qa.conf run
```

Comment: this works for me, but with play and guice, the bindings don't work when I use an alternative config resource... so strange

Comment: @nbpeth are you defining your modules in the the new config.resource? if for example you have `application.conf` with `play.modules.enabled` key -- you'll have to import `application.conf` with `import "application"` to ensure the modules are enabled in the new resource

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config), in case you did not realize it.

Without seeing your `application.conf` I can only provide a generic answer. Here is an example of providing a default value for `akka.log-config-on-start`, which will be overridden by a Java system property or an environment variable called `CONFIG_DUMP`, if defined:

```
akka {
  log-config-on-start = false
  log-config-on-start = ${?CONFIG_DUMP}
}
```

This feature of HOCON is [documented here](https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides).

Comment: Ah very cool -- I did not take a look at the HOCON. love the name Human-Optimized Config Object Notation. I posted my application conf above if you wanted to see. I'm also exploring the link you posted, thank you!

Comment: Please click on the checkbox next to your question to accept this answer, thanks